# При обновлении состояния props становятся пустыми

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

App.tsx:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import RepoList from './RepoList';
import { loadRepos } from '../actions/reposActions';

const SearchForm = React.lazy(() => import('./SearchForm'));

type AppProps = {
  repos: any,
  loadRepos: (query: string) => void
}

type AppState = {
  repos: any,
  loading: boolean,
  query: string
}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  state = {
    repos: [],
    loading: true,
    query: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.performSearch();
  }

  performSearch(query = 'react') {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.setState({
      query: query,
      repos: this.props.loadRepos(query),
      loading: false
    });
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-header">
          <div className="inner">
            <h1 className="main-title">Search in repositories GitHub</h1>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<div>SearchForm loading...</div>}><SearchForm onSearch={this.performSearch} /></React.Suspense>     
          </div>   
        </div>    
        <div className="main-content">
          {
            this.state.loading
             ? <p>Loading...</p>
             : <div><h2>{this.state.query}</h2><RepoList data={this.props.repos} /></div>
          }          
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: { repos: any; }) => ({
  repos: state.repos
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, any>) => {
  return {
    loadRepos: (query: string) => {
        dispatch(loadRepos(query))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Вначале в props все задано, но стоит отправить запрос формы, меняющий состояние, и он становится пустым, то есть падает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте конструктор:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
}
```

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а зачем он здесь нужен? P.S. Хотя вы правы.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov в официальной документации написано, что нужно всегда использовать вызов конструктора предка